# Función para dar como resultado combinaciones de los valores de un array en Python

Tags: python, pyspark, itertools

Estimada comunidad tengo una duda, deseo una funcion en python que pueda realizar lo siguiente:

dar como input una cadena: valor='ABCD'
y que la función me de como resultado las posibles combinaciones pero importando el orden:
output= ['A','B','C','D','AB','BC','CD','ABC','BCD','ABCD']

He estado investigando y en la libreria "itertools" hay algunas opciones, pero no se le acomoda ninguna función, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `resultado = [valor[i:i+largo] for largo in range(1, len(valor)) for i in range(len(valor) - largo + 1)]`